# How to set Path for ASP.NET Core Identity cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that also hosts an API.  The site uses Identity defaults so when you log in a cookie is set.  The API has been configured to use JWT Bearer authentication.

I also have a separate ASP.Net Core MVC app that hosts a Javascript SPA that communicates to this other site as the authentication server and the API.

On my dev machine these projects use different ports and when the I log in to the main API site a cookie is set and I can see that the cookie path is set to root " / ".  This is the desired behaviour since I want the Javascript SPA to know that I am authenticated and logged in.

When I deploy this to our IIS server, I give each app a virtual path like so:

Site 1:  /SPA
Site 2:  /API

When I deploy this to IIS, I notice that the cookie Path is set to "/API".

This is not the desired behaviour as the SPA app thinks I am not authenticated.

I want to be able to override this and set the cookie path explicitly to root "/".

How do I set the the cookie path while still allowing for JWT Bearer authentication?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to configure the cookie path in `ConfigureServices` like:

```
  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
  {
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
  });
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#cookie-settings